# Better way of writing these Guice Multibind statements?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have some multibinding code that looks like this:

```
bind(SuperClass.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Name1"))
                .to(SubClass1.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(SuperClass.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Name2"))
                .to(SubClass2.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
...another 20 lines of this stuff
```

I also have some code that looks like this:

```
multiBinder.addBinding().to(SomeClass1.class)
                .in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
multiBinder.addBinding().to(SomeClass2.class)
                .in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
...another 20 lines of this stuff too
```

Is there a way in Guice to do this in fewer lines/less repetitively?

EDIT: Not looking for answers like "use a for loop and iterate over set of keys".

Comment: You can use a Map of names and classes. And then in a for cycle you can do your binds.

Answer (score 3):

You could extend the DSL a little.

```
mySpecialBinding("Name1", SubClass1.class);
mySpecialBinding("Name2", SubClass2.class);

// ...

void mySpecialBinding(String name, Class<? extends SuperClass> clazz) {
    bind(SuperClass.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
                .to(clazz).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    multiBinder.addBinding().to(clazz)
                .in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
}
```